# PHP - Listing directories from subdomain in domain

Tags: php, security, subdomain

If I will open the open_basedir, meaning if I will allowed to use PHP opendir() and readdir() to list directories from my subdomain in my domain, then what security risks am I creating and how can I prevent them?

The reason why I am asking this question is the need to have access from subdomain into one of my directory which is in domain.

Comment: So you have `subdomain.example.com` pointing to `/example_dir`, and you want to list the directories in `/example_dir/` on `example.com`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is this case - domain.com has the directory foo and I want to have access to it from subdomain.domain.com

Comment: Are the domain and the subdomain on the same server? Can you give some more detail about the project, as it may help understand the problem in context.

Comment: Absolutely! This is the same server. There is the domain pc-version, which has the data in the directory, which I need to use in the mobile version of this domain. 
The schema: **domain.com/dirToRead/readData.txt** has to be opened from **mobile.domain.com/readFromTheFile.php**

Comment: So why open it through a domain at all? If they're on the same server, you can just open it through `file_get_contents()`. Your data should be completely independent of the code that's calling it.